# REM padding not calculated correctly in Safari

Tags: css, responsive-design, safari, font-size

I'm trying to build a site strictly using rem values for all elements. I have some padding on an element, however in Safari, this does not scale properly. Here is a sample:

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

div {
  padding: 0 10rem;
  border:1px solid red;
  font-size:2rem;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Changing the html font-size to a smaller value does not scale the padding properly in Safari. Appears to be ok in Chrome. Here is a screenshot comparing the two:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Your Safari probably has a different minimum font size in its user settings. 9px if the screenshot is reliable.

Comment: Good idea, i checked but its not checked :) https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/2G3w3E3x131S3x1f2P1p/Screen%20Shot%202017-10-13%20at%2011.28.56.png?v=30d200da

Comment: In that case, I can't help you, sorry, but I can't test here, as I don't have Safari. Let's hope someone who does comes along.